# What does "Returning duplicate cardTablePart entry" mean in a weblogic log?

Tags: weblogic

In my weblogic output log I get thousands upon thousands of errors containing:

```
Returning duplicate cardTablePart entry
```

: In my weblogic log. What do these "cardTablePart" errors mean and how can I find out what causes them?

Answer (score 0):

This message is seen in JRockit JVM verbose output during Garbage collections

From Sec "Example 2-9 Young Collection Output of the memdbg Module" on [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15061/verbose.htm) ,

> 3: [DEBUG][memory ] [YC#1] Returning
>   duplicate cardTablePart entry 2
>   (0x4201e000-0x4202e000)
>
> Line 3 shows what happens if several
>   threads try to process the same
>   memory.